# Javascript - Add img tag for all image links on a page

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have some image links in my document like this:

```
<p> Chrome logo: https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png</p>
<p> Google logo: https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png</p>
```

I trying to to add `img` tag to above link to show image instead of those plain links.

Also i have a [regex to find all image](http://www.regexr.com/38m5l) links but i cant use it with javascript and need your help.

the result must be look like this:

```
<p> Chrome logo: <img src="https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png" /></p>
<p> Google logo: <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" /></p>
```

Comment: Do you want to edit these files one time to turn the links into links-with-images?

Comment: What would be considered an image link? Anything ends in .png? .jpg? .image.php?displayimage=1 ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter No! just images that ends in jpg,png,gif

Comment: Javascript is code that runs in your page. Do you intend for it to generate a `document.write()` type of code so that links "appear" in the file? Or do you want to run existing html files through "a cruncher" that turns the `link-that-is-not-a-link` (because `<p>` tag is not a link) into a displayed image? Put differently - either the `https://www.google etc` is already in the file, or it is coming from somewhere else. What is the role of the javascript, in your mind?

Comment: @Floris for first q: Yes, i can't do it with replacing string?

Comment: why do you want this ? Can't you change markup ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems trivial… http://jsfiddle.net/La7XE/

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(http(s*):\/\/[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~\/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*).(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)/gi, '<img src="$1.$3" />');
```

[(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

But you should really do it server-side.